# python - how to set ticks on x-axis at specific location

Tags: python, matplotlib

On my x-axis I have days (for example 0-5000 days). Now I would like to divide this into years by dividing by 365 days so that from 0-365 it would say 2016, 366 - 2*365: 2017 etc.

What's the best way to do this?

Is there something like `ax.tickValues(xrange(0,5000,365))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is one example of how you could do it. The idea is following: First generate the tick-labels (years) you want to show starting from `2016`. Here `int(np.ceil(5000/365))` just gives you the number of years to display on the axis. Next, you generate the position where to put these ticks. Currently I am using centre of 0-365, 365-730, etc. as the location of ticks because you want 0-365 labeled as 2016 and so on.

You can adapt the below solution for your problem.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

x = range(3000)
plt.plot(x,x)

tcks = [2016+i for i in range(int(np.ceil(3000/365)))]
locs = [365*i for i in range(int(np.ceil(3000/365)))]
plt.xticks(locs, tcks)
axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(12))
```

[image]

Comment: the location of the year is fine. But is there a way to sub divide this by 12 for every year? in my plot the whole width per year is shaded using `axvspan` so it would be nice to have a little mark per month

Comment: Ok, I added that too in my answer now.

Comment: @Shaun: Now I used `365*i` as the x-ticklabel location which means 2016 starts at 0, 2017 starts at 365 and so on which is correct I think

Comment: terrific! I see this is done with `AutoMinorLocator` didn't know this exists. Thank you very much

Comment: Here 12 means that divide the region between two major ticks into 12 regions so you have basically 11 minor ticks